# Formatting Reference Number in 2013 Workflow with Year Part and Leading Zeros

Tags: workflow, document-library, formatting

I would like to set a custom reference number for documents in my site library.

The format for this reference is Currently IA17-0001.  The IA is static, the 17 represents the year, and 0001 represents how many documents have been entered in relation to the year.

I created a List with an Record and Year Column to store which record I am on.

I'm not sure how to get it, but I need to set a Workflow variable to the current Year?  I've figured how to set a variable to Today, but can't figure out how to get the Year from that value.  Ideally the year would be the last two of the year - 17, not 2017.

When I get the Record column for the current year, there might not be a row.  I plan on setting a workflow variable to the Current record for the year, if the number I get is 1, insert a row, if it's larger, I'll update the Item in the list.

After I'm not sure how to format a variable to the number with leading zeros.

If I'm not mistaken, having these two variables with my Year Part, and my Document Number with leading zeros, I should be able to Concatenate them in the String Builder.

My workflow Platform Type is a 2013 Workflow and my experience is still beginner.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What about an extra Calculated Coulmn that outputs:

```
="IA" & YEAR( [YearColumn] ) & "-" & TEXT( [RecordNr] , "0000" )
```

Comment: Wouldn't I need to create two extra columns to store Year and Record Number?  I wouldn't need them after I used them to build the Reference Number, so I figured it would be better not to create them.

Comment: Instead of [YearColumn] you could use [Created] if that works for you, all depends on where the info comes from and where it is needed. Note that I renamed the ColumnNames in the example only for explanation purpose (and because YEAR is a Function)

Comment: Thanks, I ended up having to create the Year Calculated Column since I needed the value in the workflow.  Calculation worked.